# Is there any reference implementation of Linux file system filter driver?

Tags: linux, driver, linux-device-driver, filter-driver

According to the [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/what-is-a-file-system-filter-driver-),

> A file system filter driver is an optional driver that adds value to
>   or modifies the behavior of a file system. A file system filter driver
>   can filter I/O operations for one or more file systems or file system
>   volumes. Depending on the nature of the driver, filter can mean log,
>   observe, modify, or even prevent.

I want to write a filter driver for Linux which will intercept all read requests to an `ext4` partition and redirect a few of them based on some application defined criteria. Googling on filter driver development returns more results (ideas, code snippets) for Windows than on Linux. How can I achieve something similar on Linux? If not a filter driver, then what else can achieve the same effect?

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/prashants/3839380 and this seems to be the case. But unfortunately, the only information I found on the definitions used is the source code comments.