# Linux file system filter driver: How to write and how to substitute certain path?

Tags: linux, filter, filesystems, driver

The goal is not to write file system driver, but I only know this way to reach the goal. If you know better or simpler way to achieve this, please tell me.

The essence of the issue is here [How to get rid of numerous .dotfiles in home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972937/how-to-get-rid-of-numerous-dotfiles-in-home-folder/972975?noredirect=1#comment1559601_972975). So, I think that it can be solved via file system filter driver that will filter all the file requests like `~/.*/**` (except `~/.app/*/**`)  to `~/.app/*/**`.

I found no any reference to file system driver development (only same  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362086/is-there-any-reference-implementation-of-linux-file-system-filter-driver) on stackoverflow).

I found sources of such (I think, may be I'm wrong) a driver stub.
https://gist.github.com/prashants/3839380

Is this what I need?

The only manual is unclear code comments. E.g.
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.5/source/include/linux/blk_types.h

I found out that there is make request callback and other callbacks that I can hook. But other stuff regarding to `request_queue` and `bio` is not self explained. The callback signature looks like

```
void (struct request_queue*, struct bio*);
```

E.g. [request_queue](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L312) type definition.

Am I on the right way? And if yes where can I get the documentation? I only found those [sources](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L312).

Answer (score 0):

The code linked is unrelated to the issue - it is a the wrong layer, below the filesystem. At that point there is no information what file is being requested.

I don't think this idea has legs, but if anything of the sort is to be implemented, it should be through means of something like overlayfs. Then you would translate .crap requests to go somewhere else.

That said, I don't see any use for it.